# Data format of Date including data

Tags: date-and-time

I have

```
{{{1986, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.28}, {{1986, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.26}, 
 {{1986, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.16}, {{1986, 4, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.1}, 
 {{1986, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.96}, {{1986, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.85}, 
 {{1986, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.8}, {{1986, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.77}, 
 {{1986, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0.},}, {{1986, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.73}}
```

for some data.I want to remove that hour ,min,sec part and also some missing data for some days.You can see there.I want those dates also to be filtered and not included. How the code be? I want in this format`{{{1986, 1, 15}, 2.28},{{1986, 2, 15}, 2.26},...`

Comment: You've seen `Take[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use pattern matching and replacements (with `data` assigned to your list):

```
data /. {{{__}, Null} -> Sequence[], {{a__, _, _, _}, b_} :> {{a}, b}}
```

> {{{1986, 1, 15}, 2.28}, {{1986, 2, 15}, 2.26}, {{1986, 3, 15}, 
>     2.16}, {{1986, 4, 15}, 2.1}, {{1986, 5, 15}, 1.96}, {{1986, 6, 15}, 
>     1.85}, {{1986, 7, 15}, 1.8}, {{1986, 8, 15}, 1.77}, {{1986, 10, 15},
>      1.73}}

Answer (score 5):

With the understanding that an answer has been checked, in version 9 there is `DayRound`

```
DayRound[{1986, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, All]
(* {1986, 1, 15} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pattern matching as **@Sjoerd C. de Vries** suggested, eg.

```
Cases[data, {d_, v_} :> {d[[1 ;; 3]], v}]
```

or

```
Cases[data, {{y_, m_, d_, ___}, v_} :> {{y, m, d}, v}]
```

Alternately you can extract specific parts of data using `Part` function and then combine them with `Transpose`

```
Transpose@{data[[All, 1, 1 ;; 3]], data[[All, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
data = {{{1986, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.28}, {{1986, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
2.26}, {{1986, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 2.16}, {{1986, 4, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
2.1}, {{1986, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.96}, {{1986, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
1.85}, {{1986, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.8}, {{1986, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
1.77}, {{1986, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0.},}, {{1986, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
1.73}};
```

I suggest:

```
{#[[1, 1 ;; 3]], #[[2]]} & /@ data
```

Or the more elegant but less intuitive:

```
{#1[[;; 3]], #2} & @@@ data
```